# installing sequelize-cli 4 moderate severity vulnerabilities

Tags: sequelize-cli

When I run this command " npm install --save-dev sequelize-cli "
I am getting this error:

4 moderate severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues, run:
npm audit fix

And details are:

semver  <7.5.2
Severity: moderate
semver vulnerable to Regular Expression Denial of Service - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-c2qf-rxjj-qqgw
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install sequelize-cli@5.3.0, which is a breaking change
node_modules/editorconfig/node_modules/semver
editorconfig  0.13.3 - 0.15.3
Depends on vulnerable versions of semver
node_modules/editorconfig
js-beautify  >=1.8.0-rc10
Depends on vulnerable versions of editorconfig
node_modules/js-beautify
sequelize-cli  >=5.4.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of js-beautify
node_modules/sequelize-cli

If run this :
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install sequelize-cli@5.3.0, which is a breaking change

this will lead to breaking changes